# how to dynamically print the individual vectors

Tags: r

I would like to print the vector origin created like origin1, origin2, origin3 to print dynamically. I tried the cat with paste but that does not seem to work. Any suggestion would  help.

```r
origin <- sort(c('USA','Europe','Asia'), decreasing = T)
for (i in 1:length(origin)){
  assign(paste0('origin',i), origin[i], envir = .GlobalEnv)
  cat(paste0('origin',i))
}
```

Comment: Use `get`: `cat(get(paste0('origin', i)), '\n')`

Comment: This is as per my expectation. thank you @DarrenTsai

Comment: This very much looks like an R anti-pattern. It's best to avoid get/assign. It's almost always much easier to store related data in a (possibly named) list and operate over that list rather than creating a bunch of global variables with indexes in their names.